# Plotly python add annotation to display all column values at every point

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, scatter

I am trying to plot all column values at each point when we hover over a data point in plotly

My code is as follows

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.io as pio
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import pandas as pd

# data
pio.templates.default = "plotly_white"
df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/finance-charts-apple.csv')
df_s = df[['Date','AAPL.Open','AAPL.High','AAPL.Low','dn','mavg'
        ]]
df_s = df_s.set_index('Date')
df_s.tail()
cols = df_s.columns
ncols = len(cols)

# subplot setup
fig = make_subplots(rows=ncols, cols=1, shared_xaxes=True)

for i, col in enumerate(cols, start=1):
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df_s[col].index, y=df_s[col].values, name=df_s[col].name), row=i, col=1)

fig.update_layout(
    autosize=False,
    width=1200,
    height=800,)

    
fig.show()
```

Currently when I hover over the datapoint it shows value for that column alone. I am interested in seeing
Values for 'Date','AAPL.Open','AAPL.High','AAPL.Low','dn','mavg' these columns at a particular row whenever I hover over anyplot

[image]

I tried add_annotations with no luck. Is there a way of doing it? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Marco_CH pointed out, this exact feature doesn't exist in Plotly. However, you can try using a [unified hovermode](https://plotly.com/python/hover-text-and-formatting/#unified-hovermode) on the x-axis so there is only one hoverbox, and remove the date from each hovertemplate since it's already shown at the top of the hoverbox.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px 

df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/finance-charts-apple.csv")
df1 = df.melt(id_vars=['Date']+list(df.keys()[5:]), var_name='AAPL')
fig = px.line(df1, x='Date', y='value', color='AAPL' )

## remove date from each hovertemplate
for fig_data in fig.data:
    fig_data['hovertemplate'] = fig_data['hovertemplate'].replace("<br>Date=%{x}","")
fig.update_layout(hovermode="x unified")
    
fig.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No, this doesn't work. There is an open issue for this:

https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/4755

And it doesn't seem that this will come soon. You have to decide between your way and something like:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px 

pio.templates.default = "plotly_white"
df_s = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/finance-charts-apple.csv")
df_s = df_s.melt(id_vars=["Date"]+list(df.keys()[5:]), var_name="AAPL")

fig = px.line(df_s, x="Date", y="value", color="AAPL")

fig.update_layout(
    autosize=False,
    width=1200,
    height=800,
    hovermode="x")
    
fig.show()
```

**Output:**

[image]